# How to create custom variable programatically for template in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email-templates

With the all searching so far I have found that we can add custom variable using this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$model = $objectManager->get('Magento\Variable\Model\Variable')->loadByCode('custom-variable-code');
$plain_value = $model->getPlainValue();
```

but I have no idea where to add this and what to do with plain value.
Please let me know how can I create custom variable which I can use in my **email template** globally. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To add a custom variable, please follow below admin path.

**1)** Login in to admin.

**2)** go to SYSTEM -> Custom Variable (under "Other setting").

**3)** Click "Add New Variable" button.

**4)** Enter Variable Code,Variable Name,Variable HTML Value 
[optional], Variable Plain Value[optional]

**5)** Click "Save" button.

[image]

Comment: but I need to achieve this programatically

Comment: you can check this answer to create custom variable programmatically  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41760331/magento2-create-custom-variables-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

In your custom module use install script to create progrmatically:

```
use Magento\Variable\Model\VariableFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

protected $varFActory;

public function __construct(VariableFactory $varFactory)
{
    $this->varFActory = $varFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function install(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    ModuleContextInterface $context
) {

    $variable = $this->varFActory->create();
    $data = [
        'code' => '',
        'name' => '',
        'html_value' => '',
        'plain_value' => '',

    ];
    $variable->setData($data);
    $variable->save();          
}

}
```